# How to check if .closest select has a value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need some help to check if a select has a value or not.
When I click one of the links I need to check if the first select below that link has a value or not. So if I click on link nr2, then check if the select under that has a value or not.
I have tested with variations of this, but I can´t make it work:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="1" class="thelink">Clicked a link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="felkod">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="2" class="thelink">Clicked a link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="felkod">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
var test = $$(this).closest('div > #felkod');
var sel = $$(this).closest('div > select').val()

if (test.length) {
  if (sel === '') {
    app.dialog.alert("Make a selection!")
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any input appreciated, thanks.

I got it working with this:

```
var sel = $(this).parent().parent().next().find('select').val();
            if (sel.length===0) {
               alert("You must select")
            }
```

Comment: Is `$$` a reference to jQuery in your code? Also note that `closest()` looks for parent elements, not children of siblings, and also that duplicate `id` attributes are invalid. Either make them unique or use a class instead

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: btw you have multiple elements with the same ID `felkod` an ID should always be unique

Comment: Sometimes it's worth having a re-read of what a function **actually does**, not *what it sounds like it might do*: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you could change your HTML structure so that the link and the select were both in a common container (separate from containers for other links and selects). It's *possible* to do it with your current structure, but fragile:

```
$$(".thelink").on("click", function() {
    var select = $(this).parent().parent().next().find("select");
    //...
});
```

or with event delegation:

```
$$(document.body).on("click", ".thelink", function() {
    var select = $(this).parent().parent().next().find("select");
    //...
});
```

Note I've assumed `$$` is a reference to jQuery in your code.

But if you could put a wrapper around them, like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" id="1" class="thelink">Clicked a link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="felkod">
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="#" id="2" class="thelink">Clicked a link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="felkod">
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can do it more robustly:

```
$$(".thelink").on("click", function() {
    var select = $(this).closest(".wrapper").find("select");
    //...
});
```

or with event delegation:

```
$$(document.body).on("click", ".thelink", function() {
    var select = $(this).closest(".wrapper").find("select");
    //...
});
```

---

Side note: `id` values **must** be unique in the document. You're reusing the same `id` (`felkod`) more than once.

Comment: Thanks a lot T.J. I got it working. Will update my question.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson - There's no need to update the question if this answers it.

Answer (score 0):

First `id` should be unique, you cannot use same `id` for both select elements. so I modified to `node` as dummy attribute to refer that element.

```js
var values = {};

$('.thelink').on('click', function(){
  if (!!values[$(this).attr('id')]) {
    window.alert("Done");
  }
  else{  
    window.alert("Make a selection!");
  } 
  
  event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('select').on('change', function(a,b){
  values[$(this).attr('node')] = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="first" class="thelink">Clicked a link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <select node="first">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="second" class="thelink">Clicked a link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <select node="second">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```